# Sparsely connected networks Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am working with custom-made networks in Keras, which tend to be sparsely more often than densely connected, but there is a problem. Instead of usual 10 seconds to train and evaluate the results of a network on MNIST dataset, these sparsely connected networks take about 15 mins each which is a really big difference, so my concern here is - is this the normal behavior of sparsely connected networks that are badly connected or is it something else? Also, the optimizer that I use is SGD, but I don't think that it is the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to post some of the output from both your dense and sparse network, but if you haven't changed any other parameters besides the network, then I would say the time increase is normal. **HOWEVER**, I would need to know the exact architecture of both networks to be 100% certain.

You also mentioned that you are using the optimizer SGD, which I believe is also perfectly fine. However, if you want to increase the speed of training, I would suggest you look into the Adam optimizer. This is because, while SGD generalizes better for finding the minimum, Adam is faster. [Here](https://shaoanlu.wordpress.com/2017/05/29/sgd-all-which-one-is-the-best-optimizer-dogs-vs-cats-toy-experiment/) is a blog post about the differences between SGD and Adam and which would work in your specific case.

Comment: The thing is that it is not that easy to explain the architecture of the sparse network because I am encoding it into an array and then decoding it using some algorithm, because what I am trying to do is to create a genetic model to find best possible architectures of networks. 
Would it be enough for you if I sent you a model summary or something like that? The graphic visualization doesn't work for me because of the error that goes something like "no errno in os" (of course this is not precise).